# Gesture Recognisers and Touch Began for a View in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `View`. In that `view` I added a `gestureRecogniser` for **Pan**,**Rotate** and **Pinch**. `Recogniser` takes small amount of time to detect it as a `Gesture`. But When I add **touchesBegan** function It detects the touch when I touch the finger to the screen without any delay. Any suggestion to Solve. I need `GestureRecogniser` for Pinch and Rotate the View. For Panning I need to use **TouchesBegan** function. How can i Keep both those things in a `View`

Comment: why don't you use PanGestureRecognizer? touchesBegan receives all the touches

Comment: In Pan Gesture Recognizer Small minute delay. If we use iPencil and See I can notice. But touchesBegan no Delay